# UITableView Rows With Dynamic height working in IOS 8 not working in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableview in which i need to populate rows with dynamic height.

**What I did:**

I have a textlabel whose height will be changing dynamically. So when i set the data on my cell i set it like :

```
-(void)setCommentDataOnCell:(CommentModel*) data
{


    CGFloat currentHeigh=_commentTextLabel.frame.size.height,heightDiff;

//Here is the label with dynamic height

    _commentTextLabel.text=data.commentText;
    [_commentTextLabel sizeToFit];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    heightDiff=_commentTextLabel.frame.size.height-currentHeigh;

// I change the frame of cell here ie, add the height difference in label

    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height+heightDiff)];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    commentAuthorLabel.text=data.createdUserName;

}
```

Now i have set the autolayout such that the dynamic cell is aligned to bottom as well as top of the cell's content view

[image]

Then i have set following properties for my tableview

```
commentListTableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
commentListTableView.estimatedRowHeight=44.0f;
```

**Now To What I get:**

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DiscussionDetailViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78787760'

---

**I havent implemented this selector heightForRowAt**

but i have implemented **EstimatedHeight as 75.0f** as it was for my prototype cell in my storyboard i also have a headerview for session with height 8.0f

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath method to support iOS 7.

Please refer this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/1282896